# Creating ID for a SQL Alchemy Many to Many relationship

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relationship for a pokemon social media-esque web app I'm making...

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    groups = relationship('Group', secondary ='link', back_populates="users")
    # a bunch of fields

class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    users = relationship('User', secondary ='link', back_populates="groups")
    #a bunch of fields

#this class links the users and groups to form the many to many relationship
class Link(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
    group = db.relationship(Group, backref="link")
    user = db.relationship(User, backref="link")
    
    #here are fields I'm storing inside the link (Not sure if this is the right way)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, default=2) #owner = 0, member = 1, spectator = 2
```

This all works fine for me, but now I'm trying to store another class inside of the link and it's giving me problems

```
class Link(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
    group = db.relationship(Group, backref="link")
    user = db.relationship(User, backref="link")

    pokemon = db.relationship('Pokemon', backref='link', lazy=True)

class Pokemon(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pokemon = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    link_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('link.id'))
```

My problem is that now I need an ID for the Link model and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. It doesn't automatically generate the link id for me because I already have those two other primary keys for user and group. I know I could manually set it each time but I need to automate that for my web app. I tried looking into the self-incrementing field but I was either using it incorrectly or that's not viable either. I'm pretty new to databases so I'm sorry if this is a bad question, but I'd appreciate any help I could get!

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!

I think you can add an id field like you did for others models like:

```py
class Link(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
    group = db.relationship(Group, backref="link")
    user = db.relationship(User, backref="link")
```

Now, if you want to make it stick, you will have to migrate your database.
[Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good option to do that.

By the way, the relationship you're implementing isn't a many-to-many but a one-to-many here.

You will need to add a helper table to make the relation between your Link and your Pokemon table.
More informations at the end of this page : https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

Hope it helped!